# Does git fetch pull data for all branches

Tags: git, git-fetch

If I am on a particular branch and I do a `git fetch` does it pull down all the data for that branch only or for all branches for that repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git fetch` fetches named heads or tags from one or more other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete them. It means that it updates all `<remote>/<branch>` and all the tags.

`git fetch <remote> <branch>` fetches specified branch from specified repository only.